# a problem with char** in c

Tags: c

i have an char** arr which is an array of strings and i want to erase the 2 last cell of the array  or maybe to create a new char** but without those last 2 cells
thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps you can post some code.

Comment: You'll need to know the length unless you are using some convention to single end-of-list.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the size of your array?

The code might be like this assuming the length of the array is array_size:

```
int array_size;
char **array = malloc (sizeof (char*) * array_size); 
....
free (*(array+array_size)); *(array+array_size) = NULL;
free (*(array+array_size-1)); *(array+array_size-1) = NULL;
```

In case you don't know the length, the fact that the element past last used element is NULL will help.

Then the code somewhat more complex:

```
for (char** ai = array; *ai != NULL; ai++);
ai--;
free(*ai); *ai = NULL;
ai--;
free(*ai); *ai = NULL;
```

Comment: `*(array+array_size)` is past the end of the array.

Comment: thank you
i do know the size of the array and i am trying
for ... size-2 ..
  strcpy

Answer (score 1):

How about you free the memory pointed to by the last two elements in the array, set them to zero and then separately keep track of the sizeof the array.

For example

```
unsigned int len = 10;
char **aryStr = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *)*len);
....
free(aryStr[--len])
aryStr[len] = NULL;
free(aryStr[--len])
aryStr[len] = NULL;
```

You can use the new len as a parameter to routines manipulating the array.
Alternatively you create extra value (sentinel) in your array that marks the end of data by pointing to NULL. You process the array (like a string) by iterating over it until you find a NULL value.